# why {key:value}["key"] doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

1:`{key:value}["key"]`
2:`({key:value})["key"]`
I'm wondering how the JS interpreter works on the above codes, and why **1** doesn't work and why **2** works?

Comment: Because that's how the syntax is defined.

Comment: Depending on the interpreters, some non standard code may be accepted, or there may be some older implementations that arent standard I think it must be for the same reason people put the function in paranthesises when they do (function(){alert("stuff");})()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are asking the question because you saw this effect in a JavaScript REPL (shell).  You are using a JavaScript shell which assumes the leading "{" begins a block statement instead of an object literal.

For example, if you use the JavaScript interpreter that comes with the Chrome browser, you see the following:

```
> {key:"value"}["key"]
["key"]
```

Here, Chrome saw what you entered as a block statement, followed by the expression that was an array of one element, the string `"key"`.  So it responded with the result of that expression, namely the array `["key"]`

But not all shells work this way.  If you use the interpreter with node.js, then #1 *will* work for you!

```
$ node
> {key:"value"}["key"]
'value'
>
```

In interpreters like Chrome, you have to use parentheses to tell it that you want the first part to be an object literal. (This technique, by the way, is guaranteed to work in *all* shells, including node's).

**EDIT**

As pointed out in one of the comments, if you use that construct in an expression context anywhere in an actual script, it will produce `"value"`.  It's the use in the shell that looks confusing.

This fact was actually exploited in the famous [WAT video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) by Gary Bernhardt.

Comment: #1 works fine in the browser too, just not in eval context (the console). http://jsfiddle.net/qpnMw/

Comment: True.  That is worth adding to the answer.

Comment: how about {key1:value1,key2:value2}["key2"]?

Comment: I think the key point is that {key:"value"}["key"] can be interpreted as a bracketed block of code with a label and an expression containing just a string literal, followed by an array with one string literal element, rather than an object being indexed. The syntax is ambiguous without parentheses. Console uses eval context, so it acts the way it does.

Comment: `{key1:value1,key2:value2}["key2"]` is no good without parens, because you can't have two labels in one expression like that. (By "[label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)," I mean the things that `continue` and `break` can target).

Comment: @Lanston `{key1:"value1",key2:"value2"}["key2"]` produces `'value2'` in node, but in Chrome's REPL you will get a syntax error at the second colon.  It is not a statement label.  But `{key1:"value1","value2"}["key2"]` will be `["key2"]` in Chrome.

Comment: I got it ,Once it comes with *label* ,they all make sense