# Is JavaScript Object notation proper JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

If in Chrome console I run proper JSON:

```
{"aaa":"bbb"}
```

I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

If however I run e.g.:

```
{aaa:"bbb"}
```

It dosen't complain. Also running below is fine:

```
aaa={"aaa":"bbb"}
```

I thought that proper JSON must have properties names wrapped in quotation marks so why is this happening? Is JS object notation not proper JSON?

Comment: Explain "run proper JSON". Are you using `console.log({"aaa":"bbb"})`?

Comment: JSON just stands for JavaScript Object Notation. An Object literal is JSON.

Comment: You don't need to wrap property names in quotes unless they contain spaces, mathematical operators (e.g. `+`, `-`), etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410488/why-keyvaluekey-doesnt-work/16410499#16410499 - same problem

Comment: +1 I didn't even know `aaa:"bbb"` was valid js syntax. Also don't mix up JSON (which is a data interchange format) with JavaScript syntax like object literals and such.

Comment: @PHPglue: What you are saying is incorrect. JSON is a **language-independent**, textual data exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML. It was **inspired** by JavaScript's object literal syntax. However, a JS object literal is a syntactical element very specific to the JavaScript language. There are elements in JavaScript for which there is no equivalent in JSON, for example functions: `{foo: function() {}}` or operators: `{foo: 1 + 1}`. So please, don't add to the already existing confusion. JSON and a JS object literal are two completely different things.

Comment: To put your experiment in perspective: If I put CSV in the console, I get a runtime error: `foo,42,21`: `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`. However, if I quote the string, it "works": `"foo",42,21`. That's the same what you are doing, just with a different data format (JSON). You are directly evaluating some data format as JavaScript and modify it (arbitrarily) until it coincidentally becomes valid JS. Of course JSON was inspired by JavaScript object literal syntax, but it's still a different beast.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is caused by grammar/parsing context.

Given `{"aaa":"bbb"}` as a program, this is a [*Block [statement]*](http://es5.github.io/#x12.1) where "aaa" is a *String* followed by a colon and is thus Invalid Syntax. It can be minimally reproduced as: `"aaa":"bbb"`, as the braces did nothing but add confusion.

Given `{aaa:"bbb"}` as a program, this is a *statement* where `aaa` (an *Identifier*) is a [*Label*](http://es5.github.io/#x12.12) followed by the string `"bbb"` (also in statement context). It is fine, but it does *not* return an object. Likewise, it is equivalent to `aaa:"bbb"` in statement context.

Given `aaa={"aaa":"bbb"}` as a program, now the `{..}` is parsed in a *expression context* and treated as an [Object Literal](http://es5.github.io/#A.3); the resulting object is assigned to the variable. An expression context can be forced with other grammar constructs, such as `+{"aaa":"bbb"}`, `({"aaa":"bbb"})` or, more usefully, `console.log({"aaa":"bbb"})`.

With all that out of the way, because the JavaScript Object Literal syntax simply didn't apply in two out of the three cases:

JSON is [*almost*-but-not-quite](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) a proper-subset of JavaScript Object Literals; use proper JSON tooling and validation.